# php echo variable without quotes around it

Tags: php, html, echo, quotes

I feel kind of stupid asking this question but here it is: I have a text variable from my mysql database that I'm simply trying to print on the html page. This text contains HTML tags that will be interpreted by browser.

The current code is

```
<div class="sectionContainer">
    <?php echo htmlentities($prize['description'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') ?>
</div>
```

In the browser I end up having:

```
<div class="sectionContainer">
    "<p>Some HTML content</p>"
</div>
```

How do I get rif of the quotes so that the browser can interprete the HTML tags?

Comment: Why have you stored the quotes in the database?

Comment: Looks like the value of `$prize['description']` includes the literal quote chars, from your description.  Remove them with `<?php echo htmlentities(trim($prize['description'], '"'),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') ?>` -- or even better, figure out where they're getting injected in the first place.

Comment: `trim($prize['description'],'"')` didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="sectionContainer">
    <?php echo $prize['description'] ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, now I feel stupid. Your solution worked. Any idea why htmlentities would add quotes?

Comment: `htmlentities` doesn't add quotes. It *only* converts them.

Comment: AFAIK, `ENT_QUOTES` only converts quotes; the quotes must already have been present.

Answer (score 0):

You stored the description in the database with quotes. Remove those quotes.

Comment: I already checked and I can't see any quotes in the database.